# Outside handling on a condition i a row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have slowly found that everything goes faster when I work in dataframes and I must calculat new values, ​​which must also be in the data frame. But what if I want to run through a column, row for row in the dataframe with an if statment and print out the row, if the statement is true. Do I then have to use a for loop or can I do that also on a dataframe.

I havent solved yet, so I try again

```
for ticker in tickers:


        df = pd.read_csv('calcuatet_daily_stock_dfs/' + ticker + '.csv')
        df = df.tail(1)

        (here I change the dataframe)

        if df['Indicator Count'] == 9:
            print(ticker)
```

I get the fellowing error message

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Actually, I don't have to print the ticker, I have to save it in a csv file, but it will come later

Comment: What kind of operation involves printing? This is too broad, please be more specific.

Comment: It did not have to be printing, it was just for testing, it should actually call a function

Comment: That depends on the function, then. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can print out an entire row if a condition is true with something like this, example data included:

```
df[df.timestr >50]                                                                                                                                                                  

   load                         timestamp  timestr
0     0  2019-10-30 14:45:42.710000-04:00   124219
1     0  2019-11-11 07:08:09.640000-04:00   124220
```

You can also chain those conditions with | and & as long as you enclose each condition in parens ()